# Bash: php comand not found when called from a script run with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, shell-scripting, command-line-interface

I have this weird problem. The `php` command is not found in one specific sitiation.
I try to call the command in three different ways. Only one of them fails:

[image]

1. Being user `john` I create a simple script which calls `php --version`. Then as user `root` I call that script like this: `sudo -u john ./script.sh`
   This way the `php` command is not found.
2. Being `root` I invoke the command directly like this: `sudo -u john php --version`
   No problem here, the command does exist.
3. I call the script directly as user 'john': `./script.sh`
   It works fine too.

What is causing this?

The problem happens with other users too, not just `john`, and it happens on this particular machine only.
The OS is CentOS 5.9.

**EDIT:** Also, other commands like `gcc`, `perl` or `python` don't present this problem. The `php` command is the only one I found so far with the problem.

Comment: May I suggest comparing path variables on the accounts?
/home/"username"/.bash_profile

Simply add php executable location to the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your test script lacks a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). No soup for you.
2. The subshell being invoked by your script is not using the same `PATH` variable as your interactive shell. Type `echo $PATH` to see your current path variable, and set this `PATH` variable within the script.

As for why the `PATH` variable isn't consistent between the two:

- Because you aren't specifying the shebang line, you have no insurance that the shell being invoked is the same as your interactive shell. It could be sourcing different configuration files entirely.
- Different configuration files get sourced depending on how a shell is executed. You are inside of an interactive shell, and your script is a non-interactive shell. Assuming you're trying to use `bash`, consult `man bash` and begin reading at the `INVOCATION` section near the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks. The difference in the $PATH variable was the problem. The `php` command wasn't in `/usr/bin` as it normaly is, so I just added a symlink to it and problem solved.

Comment: @GetFree I really don't recommend that symlink, it will just make things confusing. The proper solution to the problem is to understand why the `PATH` variable was different, and correct it in the proper configuration file.

Comment: I think the difference in PATH is due to .bash_profile as @Vick said. The PATH inside the script was just `/usr/bin:/bin` while in the interactive shell it was a much longer list of paths.

Comment: @GetFree I know about `.bash_profile`, I was directing you to the invocation docs earlier. Symlinks aren't the right way to solve this problem in a professional IT environment, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @AndrewB Nice answer as usual

Comment: I understand, it's not an elegant solution. But in my particular situation it's faster because the script is present in several user accounts. I'll keep in mind your advice, thanks.

Comment: Specifying the **absolute path** to the `php` binary in the script would be my preferred solution. This makes your script independent of any `$PATH` variable (although this _could_ also be a problem when different users are intended to run different PHP binaries).

Comment: @Lukas, another problem is that the absolute path to the php binary is not the same across different OSs

Comment: @GetFree And neither is the value of `PATH` for a bash script. I guess you will have to do _some_ work when porting a script to another OS or distribution.

Comment: Check for **secure_path** on sudoers `sudo -V | grep 'Value to override'`